# Is this Recursion + Linq example inefficient?

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

I have a hierarchy of of groups, and I want to get a collection of all the lowest level groups (or leaves if we'll look at this as a tree).

I wrote the following code. Is it inefficient?

```
public static class FeatureWeightGroupExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IFeatureWeightGroup> GetLeafGroups(this IFeatureWeightGroup featureWeightGroup)
    {
        return GetLeafGroupsRecursive(featureWeightGroup).ToList();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IFeatureWeightGroup> GetLeafGroupsRecursive(IFeatureWeightGroup featureWeightGroup)
    {
        if (!featureWeightGroup.ChildGroups.Any())
            return Enumerable.Repeat(featureWeightGroup, 1);

        return featureWeightGroup.ChildGroups.Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<IFeatureWeightGroup>(),
                                                        (allGroups, group) =>
                                                        allGroups.Concat(GetLeafGroupsRecursive(group)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I kept reading it as *feather weight* until I realised it says **feature** :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return featureWeightGroup.ChildGroups.Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<IFeatureWeightGroup>(),
                                                    (allGroups, group) =>
                                                    allGroups.Concat(GetLeafGroupsRecursive(group)));
```

It looks like it can be replaced with:

```
return featureWeightGroup.ChildGroups
           .SelectMany(g => GetLeafGroupsRecursive(group));
```

Which probably will not be much better from performance point of view, but looks cleaner.

Comment: Actually it *would* be much better performance. The `Aggregate` version would instantiate many `Concat` iterators, which would constantly forward `MoveNext()` calls to each other, while your improvement instantiates only one `SelectMany` iterator.

Answer (score 5):

As already pointed out by *Snowbear* and my comment on his answer, you can improve the performance *and* readability by using `SelectMany` instead of `Concat`.

However, I notice that you are using `ToList()` at the end anyway. This pulls into question the benefit of using LINQ and all those `SelectMany` iterators in the first place. Using LINQ sacrifices performance at the benefit of lazy evaluation, but you are not using the lazy-evaluation aspect. Therefore, if performance is what you are after, then don’t use LINQ that much:

```
public static class FeatureWeightGroupExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IFeatureWeightGroup> GetLeafGroups(this IFeatureWeightGroup featureWeightGroup)
    {
        var list = new List<IFeatureWeightGroup>();
        populateList(list, featureWeightGroup);
        return list;
    }

    private static void populateList(List<IFeatureWeightGroup> list, IFeatureWeightGroup featureWeightGroup)
    {
        if (!featureWeightGroup.ChildGroups.Any())
            list.Add(featureWeightGroup);
        else
            foreach (var childGroup in featureWeightGroup.ChildGroups)
                populateList(list, childGroup);
    }
}
```

This is the most performance-optimised way I can think of, while at the same time also being significantly easier to read than the original *or* the `SelectMany` alternative.

Comment: +1 for the answer.  -0.5 for lack of curly braces in your if and foreach statements (which still rounds up to +1).  IMO, curly braces are never optional.

Comment: @Saeed: It’s totally fine for you to have that opinion, but try not to let that turn into intolerance of other people’s opinions.

Comment: last I checked, this is a code review forum where style comments are encouraged.  I was merely pointing out that I don't agree with that style point in your answer, so my vote should not be seen as condoning it.  Not sure how that qualifies as intolerance.

Comment: @Saeed: I’m just saying. No harm done. :) Thanks for the upvote, anyway!